# Notepad++ Getting rid of everything in a line except first word and few special words

Tags: regex, notepad++

Hello I have a text from which I am looking to delete everything else except the first word and few special words.

> acme - **noun** the highest level or degree attainable;
>
> acquiesce - **verb** to agree or express agreement
>
> adamant - **adj** impervious to pleas, persuasion, requests, reason; **noun** very hard native crystalline carbon valued as a gem
>
> adduce - **verb** advance evidence for

Here I have to retain 'the first word', "verb", "adj", "noun" and delete everything else;
so that it becomes

> acme **noun**
>
> acquiesce **verb**
>
> adamant **adj noun**
>
> adduce **verb**

Is there any Python-Script or Regex to do it in Notepad++; Thanks.

Comment: does it have to be Notepad++?

Comment: not necessarily, any windows text editor would be fine

Answer (score 3):

Try this with Notepad++

*Find what?*

```
\s*[-;]\s*( adj| verb| noun)[^\r\n;]*(;$)?
```

or matching other words then adj, werb, noun too:

```
\s*[-;]\s*( \S+)[^\r\n;]+(;$)?
```

matches words precided by - or ; remembers that word and replaces everything to line end or ; with it.

*Replace with:*

```
\1
```

[image]

Comment: Does this deal with the `adamant` entry correctly?

Comment: In my test with Notepad++ v6.5.2 both patterns did output what you wanted. Did you *replace with:* `\1` ?

Comment: I see - you are matching "the first word after a semicolon", rather than "one of these special words". I see how that works, as long as the formatting is consistent.

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression that matches what you want could look like this:

```
^(\w+)\s+-\s+(\w+)(?:.*?(?=(adj|verb|noun)))?(?:(?:noun|verb|adj)(?:.*)?)?
```

See demo at http://regex101.com/r/yR5jW5

Note - this doesn't match "three or more special words". I don't have time to figure out why not; but it's probably something obvious. This should get you started though.